# How do some SAR ADCs allow the input range to be 0 to 2xVref?

Tags: adc, dac

If the capacitive DAC on the ADC uses Vref, would it not output a signal from 0 to Vref to the comparator? How would the comparator work if the input signal is greater than Vref since it would always output all 1's.

The [AD7914](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD7904_7914_7924.pdf) allows the input of the ADC to be 0 to Vref or 0 to 2xVref by changing a bit in a register.

Does it use an internal resistor divider to reduce the input by half?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2's complement or unsigned SAR conversions always use the "remainder voltage" /2 to decimate then next bit. 
So I believe using Vref/2 as the comparator level for SAR conversion is normal and the input full-scale is 0 to Vref.  i.e.

- MSBit conversion 0 means < Vref/2 and 1 means >= Vref/2

In this chip Vref = 2.5V and the logic supports 3V and 5V supplies however if the the user sets 1 bit in a register to indicate 2xVref is going to be used i.e. 0~5V analog in, then the logic supply MUST BE 5V.  This feature prevents the comparator from having to do level shifting down and prevents over-voltage to the logic side where the analog comparator drives the logic in successive approximation register ( SAR )steps. So the analog input range comparator input must not exceed the logic supply.